# Finding the local area network IP and MAC address using PHP code

Tags: php

Finding the local area network IP and MAC address using PHP code.

Below code is working on Windows. But didn't work on Raspberry Pi. Please help me.

```
$ipadd = gethostbyname(trim(`hostname`));
    echo $ipadd."<br>";
    $add = explode(".",$ipadd);
    array_pop($add);
    $addre = implode(".",$add);
    $address = $addre.".";
    $i = 1;
    while($i < 254) 
    {
        pingAddress($address.$i,$ipadd);
        $i++;
    }
    function pingAddress($ip,$dip) 
    {
        $pingresult = exec("ping -n 1 -w 1 $ip", $outcome, $status);
        if (0 == $status) 
        {
            if ($ip != $dip) 
            {
                $cmd = "arp -a " . $ip;
                $macadd = exec($cmd);
                $str = $macadd;
                $mac = explode(" ",$str);
                echo $ip." - ".$mac[11]."<br>"; 
            }
            else
            {
                $string = exec('getmac');
                $mac = substr($string, 0, 17); 
                echo $ip." - ".$mac."<br>";
            }
        } 
        else 
        { 
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Pi is probably running *nix and ping has a slightly different set of flags.

I assume your using -n to say just 1 ping, on *nix it's -c.  You could miss this parameter out and just use the -w to limit the pings.  So code is...

```
$pingresult = exec("ping -w 1 $ip", $outcome, $status);
```

Answer (score 0):

On Raspberry Pi zero W and PHP7, i use (for onboard wifi adaptator) :

```
//get mac address
$mac=file_get_contents("/sys/class/net/wlan0/address");
echo "mac=".$mac;
```